# Set Notation Equivalence Class of Lines with Given Slope

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

In set notation, how can I express that: for an equivalence relation over $\mathbb{R}$ (say $a$R$b$ for example) one class includes non-horizontal and non-vertical lines passing through the origin, while all other classes consist of single lines.

For example, lines through the origin for arbitrary positive slope $c \gt 0$ could be expressed as:

$\forall a\in \mathbb{R} \ \ [a]=\{ \ b \in \mathbb{R} \ | \ b = c \cdot a \}$

But, how do I express that $c \ne \infty$ (i.e. that the line is not vertical), and what about the classes of a single line?

This is related to a problem from a proofs course for which I have determined the solution in English as above but have abstracted away the details of the problem seeing as I am merely unsure about how to formally express my solution and would ultimately like to apply the details myself and thus do the problem myself.

Comment: I _hope_ that the instructor in your proofs class would _much rather_ read your "solution in English" than decipher unnecessary formalism.  Was the question from your instructor asked in English with mathematical symbols only when necessary, or was it all formal?

Comment: @EthanBolker Thank you for the swift response. The question in my proofs class was formal, but my instructor would probably accept the English response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My professor said that: since the relation was of the form $x$R$y$ such that $x=a^n y$ for $n$ an integer, it was sufficient to denote the equivalence class as $[x] = \{y \ | \ a^n x = y\}$ since $a^{-n} x$ would be redundant for $n$ an integer.